# Screen view jumps when tapping on element in mobile with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mobile, touch

For some reason, sometimes when I view my visualization in mobile browser and tap on the nodes (circles) the phone screen view jumps to the top left corner. I do not see why that would happen, and why sometimes it works.

You can see the problem by viewing https://codepen.io/kvyb/pen/dRoXpp in mobile browser.

This is the code for my hover interaction, but I do not think it is causing the problem:

```
var node = svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9)
            div .html('<div class="container text-center">'+"<img class='candidate' src=" + "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/DataVis/master/HTicons/"+d.clusternumber+".png"+">"+ '</div><p class="tooltiptext">I said "'+d.text+' " '+d.wordcount+" times,<br> which amounts to "+ (Math.round(d.perc * 100) / 100)+"%<br> of all words I used<br> in my speeches in 2016</p>") 
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })          
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div .transition()       
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```

I thought it could be due to me using two hover instances, which do different things, but removing one did not solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently, after some testing I can draw a conclusion that it is a problem with codepen. When hosted here: http://depicture.io/usa-presidential-words-2016.html the nodes interact via touch perfectly fine.